# Order query by relationship count laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, relationships

So i got an section people can make comments and give like to those comments.
i want to organizate the comments based on how many likes does it have.

so i use something like this

```
$art = Article::with('category')
->with(array('comments' => function($comments){
    //i get the comments related to the article and the count of likes it has
    $comments->with('likesCount');
}))
->find($id);
```

this is the model

```
<?php

class Comment extends Eloquent {
    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('CommentsLike','comment_id');
    }
    //here i take the count of likes, if i use ->count() it throw
    public function likesCount()
    {
      return $this->likes()
        ->groupBy('comment_id')
        ->selectRaw('comment_id,count(*) as comment_likes');
    }
}
```

how can i sort my comment based on what i got in `likesCount`

Answer (score 0):

Use **orderBy()** to `likesCount()` function.

```
public function likesCount()
{
  return $this->likes()
    ->groupBy('comment_id')
    ->selectRaw('comment_id,count(*) as comment_likes')
    ->orderBy('comment_likes', 'desc');
}
```